# Automate the authentication process through the Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, oauth

Can anyone suggest how to do automatic authentication via Facebook API. For example I have a login and password, and I need to automatically get access_token. While that comes to mind only the cURL. What are some solutions?

I want to simplify the steps through the login PHP SDK.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for unit testing, check out the [Test Users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/) documentation, because Test users when accessed via the API have a login_url you can hit automatically and get a user session.

For other use-cases, follow the regular [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) docs - there is no user/password login option via the API - you need to use the Oauth flow